# efficient longest common subsequence algorithm library?

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, dynamic-programming, lcs

I'm looking for a (space) efficient implementation of an LCS algorithm for use in a C++ program. Inputs are two random access sequences of integers.
I'm currently using the dynamic programming approach from the wikipedia page about LCS. However, that has O(mn) behaviour in memory and time and dies on me with out of memory errors for larger inputs.
I have read about Hirschberg's algorithm, which improves memory usage considerably, Hunt-Szymanski and Masek and Paterson. Since it isn't trivial to implement these I'd prefer to try them on my data with an existing implementation. Does anyone know of such a library? I'd imagine since text diff tools are pretty common, there ought to be some open source libraries around?

Comment: Are you interested in the actual longest common subsequence or just its length?

Comment: Disappointed that a few quick web searches didn't turn up anything especially useful (loads of ad hoc implementations for `char` in C, but nothing with either Hirschberg's linear-space speedup or templated on element type for C++).  If you do find (or create :D) anything, please update!

Comment: Also: Not directly on-topic, but Myers had a couple of O(nd) algorithms, where d is the number of edits needed.  Very nice for inputs that you expect to be similar!  (I think one of these is still used in most `diff`s.)

Comment: The best I have found so far is http://wordaligned.org/articles/longest-common-subsequence Although you have to be careful: the C++ version increments iterators past the end when performing the recursive calls. Needs fixing. Also, it does not implement the common prefix/suffix optimization.

Answer (score 3):

When searching for things like that, try scholar.google.com. It is much better for finding scholarly works. It turned up 
http://www.biotec.icb.ufmg.br/cabi/artigos/seminarios2/subsequence_algorithm.pdf
this document, a "survey of longest common subsequences algorithms".

Comment: Grudging +1 because the OP really wants library implementations of said algorithms, not descriptions.  But probably a useful paper anyway.

Comment: Also it would be helpful to know the date of publication & other details.

Answer (score 0):

[Hirschberg's Algorithm](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~lloyd/tildeAlgDS/Dynamic/Hirsch/) embeds a javascript implementation : almost C.

Answer (score -1):

Not C++ but Python but I think usable.

http://wordaligned.org/articles/longest-common-subsequence